# Could not autowire field: can't to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, shiro

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: protected com.cms.service.FolderService com.cms.action.BaseAction.folderService; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.cms.service.FolderService field com.cms.action.BaseAction.folderService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set com.cms.service.FolderService field com.cms.action.BaseAction.folderService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy22
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:146)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.throwSetIllegalArgumentException(UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.java:150)
    at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.set(UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.java:63)
    at java.lang.reflect.Field.set(Field.java:657)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:514)
    ... 32 more
```

this is my baseAction

```
public class BaseAction {

    @Autowired
    protected FolderService folderService;

    @Autowired
    protected ArticleService fileService;

    @Autowired
    protected TemplateService themeService;

    @Autowired
    protected HeadlineService headlineService;

    protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());
}
```

and that's my FolderService

```
@Service
public class FolderService {

    protected final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private FolderDao folderDao;

    @Autowired
    private AdminFolderDao adminFolderDao;

 ...................next is the java method

}
```

Comment: since this has to do with proxy could you post your complete configuration and mention if you do any transaction management, AOP etc ?

Comment: I extract interface for the service, and is ok, thank you very much

Comment: Post whatever you did to fix your problem as an answer and mark it as resolved or delete the question altogether.

Comment: How was the problem solved? Do post an answer.

Comment: I suppose you finally found your way out of this problem, but the solution is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36556358/java-lang-illegalargumentexception-cannot-set-to-com-sun-proxy-proxy/36556498#comment60713609_36556498

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually this means there is an AOP proxy delegating to your bean.  For example, if you have annotated one of your methods with `@Transaction`.

Comment: if class need @Transaction annotation, then how to do?

Comment: @sendreams Please use interfaces instead of implementations. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579118/spring-autowiring-fails-with-transactional

Answer (score 2):

Forcing aop to wave by using cglib proxies by configuring

```
spring.aop.proxy-target-class=true
```

helps.

Refer [this article](https://www.credera.com/blog/technology-insights/open-source-technology-insights/aspect-oriented-programming-in-spring-boot-part-2-spring-jdk-proxies-vs-cglib-vs-aspectj) for more information

Comment: Keep in mind that links can get broken. It's nice that you annotated it briefly; consider adding more details to your post directly.

Answer (score 1):

When the implementation is proxied, you should declare the member variables with interfaces instead of implementations. See [spring autowiring fails with @Transactional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579118/spring-autowiring-fails-with-transactional).

For example, instead of:

```
    @Autowired
    protected FolderService folderService;
```

You should use:

```
    @Autowired
    protected IFolderService folderService;
```

where `IFolderService` is the interface that `FolderService` implements.

Answer (score 0):

Move @Transaction from your DAO object to the Service object.