# spring autowiring fails with @Transactional

Tags: spring, jpa, proxy-classes

I want to use @Transactional annotation in the save() method of UserService(concrete class) as follows:

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Transactional
    public Long save(User userCommand, BindingResult result) {
    ...
    }

}
```

I will use this service in MyRealm by autowiring.

```
public class MyRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

}
```

However, it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set n.r.c.s.user.UserService field n.r.c.s.realm.MyRealm.userService to com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48
```

Of course, it works if I remove the @Transational annotation.

My transaction manager setting is as follows:

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"></property>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

Please, let me know what's wrong with my code?

Do I need to set up something like proxy?

Comment: I suppose, MyRealm or AuthorizingReal are spring beans ?, have you intent to use mode=aspectj in your transaction manager

Comment: add this line to your spring-conf `<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="false" />` , but still are you sure that MyRealm Is context aware ?

Comment: Is that your actuall `UserService` or do you define some interfaces on it?

Comment: @Koitoer, MyRealm has "Component" annotation in order to enable "autowiring" as a spring bean.

Comment: @AntJavaDev I put the option you mentioned, but it doesn't make any difference. I'm still confused. :(

Comment: @M.Deinum my `UserService` is a concret class which doesn't implement any interface.

Comment: Then you have an issue in your AOP setup leading to a proxy of a proxy.

Comment: @AntJavaDev: why proxy-target-class="false" ? Should it not be  proxy-target-class="true" ? It should allow class-based proxying?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When proxying is enabled you need to use interfaces, not implementations.

```
@Service
public class UserService implements SomeInterface {

@Transactional
public Long save(User userCommand, BindingResult result) {
...
}

}


public class MyRealm extends AuthorizingRealm {

@Autowired
private SomeInterface userService;

}
```

If you do not want to do this, you can always check your AOP config. you are probably doing proxy for a proxy somewhere.

Comment: Not per definition... Spring can handle class based proxies as well.

Comment: Yes, yes, I know, that's why I added this one last line. I get your comment when I was writing it. But sure good you've noticed that I forgot about it.

Comment: @szefuf I made an interface `UserService` which has severl method declarations, and I implemented `UserServiceImpl` with method definitions. I put the `Transactional` annotation, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @szefuf Your answer was correct. It was my fault because I renamed `UserService` to `UserServiceImpl` using eclipse "refactoring" menu. It made all the references were replaced, too. That's why I still declared `UserServiceImp`, concrete class. Thank you.